# Выдача значение n-ого элемента по запросу пользователя

Tags: javascript, числа-фибоначчи

Необходимо написать функцию генерирующую последовательно числа ряда Фибоначчи.

По запросу пользователя номера элемента при помощи написанной функции выводить на экран элементы ряда Фибоначчи, пока пользователь не перестанет их запрашивать

Получилось реализовать данную задачу, но  ряд становится видным лишь после окончания запросов:

```
var fibonacci = [0, 1];
do {
var n = +prompt("Введите значение","");
Fib(n);
} while (n>0);

function Fib() {
for (i = 2; i < n; i ++) {
fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i-1] + fibonacci[i-2];
}
document.write(fibonacci.slice(n-1,n) + '<br>');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код не успевается отобразится потому что цикл приоритетней чем изменение документа. Я переделал Ваш код чтобы вызывать следующий `prompt` только после 50 мс (чтобы документ успел изменится), для этого пришлось переделать цикл в функцию рекурсию. Также лучше не использовать `document.write`, по крайней мере в реальных проектах, я заменил на `innerHTML`.

```js
var fibonacci = [0, 1];

ask()

function ask () {
  var n = +prompt("Введите значение","");
  
  if (!n)
    return

  Fib(n);
  
  setTimeout(ask, 50)
}

function Fib(n) {
  for (i = 2; i < n; i ++) {
    fibonacci[i] = fibonacci[i-1] + fibonacci[i-2];
  }
  
  document.body.innerHTML += fibonacci.slice(n-1,n) + '<br>';
}
```